# Add and remove list items controls dynamically in Razor pages

Tags: javascript, list, asp.net-core, dynamic, razor-pages

im using Razor pages and in my page model i have empty list. I need it to by filled by user. And i do not know how many items there will be. Currently im using post methods to add inputs to my page like this:

```
     public async Task OnPostAddLicence()
        {
            await SetDials();
            LicenceList.Add(new Licence());
        }

        public async Task OnPostRemoveLicence(int index)
        {
            await SetDials();
            ModelState.Clear();
            LicenceList.RemoveAt(index);
        }
```

problem with this aproach is that it reloads the page and scroll to TOP of the page.
Unfortunately i did not find any way to scroll back on where i was. And because its razor pages maintain scroll position is not working.

so i would like to add these item dynamicaly with javascript. i tried using this:

```
<div id="divCont">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Salaries[0].HoursWorked" placeholder="Odpracovaných hodin">
            <input type="button" onclick="AddTextBox()" value="Add" />
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function GetDynamicTextbox(value) {
            return '<div><input type="text" name="txttest" style="width:200px;" asp-for="Salaries[0].HoursWorked" /><input type="button" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)" value="Remove" /></div>';
        }
        function AddTextBox() {
            var div = document.createElement('DIV');
            div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextbox("");
            document.getElementById("divCont").appendChild(div);
        }
        function RemoveTextBox(div) {
            document.getElementById("divCont").removeChild(div.parentNode.parentNode);
        }

    </script>
```

but it is not binding the value to the list.
And all others methods that i could find online are not working with razor pages but just mvc

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you cannot bind data to `input`?If so,sometimes asp-for cannot work,you can have a try to change `asp-for="Salaries[0].HoursWorked"` to

```
id="Salaries_@(0)__HoursWorked"
name="Salaries[@(0)].HoursWorked"
value=@Salaries[0].HoursWorked
```

Here is a example to show how to bind data without `asp-for`:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Locations[0].Street" /></td>
<input type="text" id="Locations_0__Street" name="Locations[0].Street" value=@Model.Locations[0].Street />
```

result:

[image]

Here is a worked demo to show the binding:
Page:

```
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="@Model.postdata.data[0].id" class="form-control" />
    <input id="postdata_data_0__name" name="postdata.data[0].name" value="@Model.postdata.data[0].name" class="form-control" />
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

PageModel:

```
public class TestModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Postdata postdata{ get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            List<TestDT> data = new List<TestDT>();
            TestDT testDT = new TestDT { id = 1, name = "test1" };
            TestDT testDT2 = new TestDT { id = 2, name = "test2" };
            data.Add(testDT);
            data.Add(testDT2);
            postdata = new Postdata();
            postdata.data = data;
            return Page();
        }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            return Page();
        }

    }
```

Result:
[image]